# What Generated Classes and IDs That Is Always Used On All Themes?

Tags: themes, css, core, post-class

Just wondering if there is a way to get a complete list of wordpress generated `css classes and ids` that is always automatically assigned to any themes.

I've read [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/default-wordpress-generated-css-cheat-sheet-for-beginners/), but it seem not list them completely.

May be someone here can pointing me to what wordpress core file/s that is doing that?

Answer (score 2):

The list you are referring to was done start to mid 2013, which can be a bit outdated as the was major improvements/new feutures like

- The TINYMCE editor undergone major modifications and upgrades as from version 3.9
- Version 4 saw the introduction of new shortcodes like the video shortcode and audio playlist, just to name a few
- In the back end plenty of new features saw the light
- The introduction of new features/functions/template tags like pagination functions that came with version 4.1

So, in my opinion, there can never be a completed list of all the classes used in Wordpress by default. The best is, dig into core

Here are few places you can start (*CAVEAT: This is not by any means a complete list, but just some of the major functions/etc. This list and references are for the current verion of Wordpress which is 4.1*)

- [post classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) - see [wp-includes/post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)
- [body classes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) - see [wp-includes/post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0)
- [comment classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class) - see  [wp-includes/comment-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L0)
- navigation menu classes - see [wp-includes/nav-menu.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L0)
- default widget classes - see [wp-includes/default-widgets.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php)
- WYSIWYG editor classes - see [wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php)
- Several shortcode classes - [see wp-includes/media.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php)